# make my html code responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am looking for a tool with which I can make the html page I created responsive. Are there any tools in which I can just paste the page code and give me a responsive variant? I searched using Google, but no luck finding one for now. If you know any can you please share that information with me and everyone interested? Thank you!

Comment: before heading to bootstrap [check this link bro](https://medium.com/frontend-and-beyond/8b3812c7007c) bootstrap having everything you need.Foundation helps you to learn a lot.. :) my op Foundation and also check CSS3 media queries.[for your own made](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without a lot of work use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), it's very simple to use and have a good documentation full with examples.

You can also define your css margin, width, height, etc with % instead of pixels, but this don't always fit good.

You can use media queries for all resolutions you need, but if you want you're website to be full responsive it will give you a lot of work.

So the best choice is give a try on Twitter Bootsrap, and if you have any doubt, ask for help.

EDIT: It's not just paste the code and you get the resposnive design, you need to use the grid system but it's easy !

Answer (score 0):

you can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) , it is responsive ready

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Restive Plugin](http://plugin.restive.io). It won't make your HTML code responsive automatically [i.e. you have to install and configure it], but it enables you to add these Responsive features quite easily. Have a look at this blog post as well: http://blog.restive.io/posts/5852603/getting-started-with-restive-plugin

Full Disclosure: I developed the plugin

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using width in px, you need to define them in %.
This is the best answer i can give you based on your information that you have given.

You can look into Bootstraps responsive code if you want a look inside a responsive grid.
http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a  [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=building%20a%20responsive%20website&rlz=1C1RXDB_en-GBGB547GB547&oq=building%20a%20responsive%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4651j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) search on Responsive webpages? There are some good tutorials out there.

As far as I know there are no tools for you to just paste your code and it turns it into a responsive page.

[Here are some good tools to help you create a responsive page](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/rwd-tools/)

Comment: Would be nice if you could give your reasons for the downvote?

Comment: Obviously OP just wants ze codez to copy and pasta and doesn't like to read.